# How to get data from FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm using `FutureProvider.value` in provider package and trying to get location data with `Provider.of<T>(context)` from this provider, but I can only get null. Instead of that, I can get the data when I use `FutureBuilder`, so I think my code around provider is wrong. I hope you will help me.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final LocationService _locationService = LocationService();

  Future<LocationModel?> getUserLocation() async {
    final locationData = await _locationService.getLocation();

    if (locationData != null) {
      final placeMark =
          await _locationService.getPlaceMark(locationData: locationData);
      if (placeMark == null) {
        return null;
      }
      return LocationModel(
        country: placeMark.country ?? '',
        adminArea: placeMark.administrativeArea ?? '',
        subAdminArea: placeMark.subAdministrativeArea ?? '',
        city: placeMark.locality ?? '',
        subCity: placeMark.subLocality ?? '',
        street: placeMark.street ?? '',
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return FutureProvider<LocationModel?>.value(
      value: getUserLocation(),
      initialData: null,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Welcome!'),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile');
                },
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 205, 106, 99)),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text('--I want to display location here--'),
              Text(Provider.of<LocationModel?>(context)?.city! ??
                  Provider.of<LocationModel?>(context).toString()),
              FutureBuilder(
                  future: getUserLocation(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<LocationModel?> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data!.city!);
                    }
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    ......
```

Comment: I changed child parameter to builder parameter in FutureProvider.value and used context.watch() for getting the data. I inserted the code for getting the data, then Provider.of<T>(context) got to work ,too. I don't know why this code is getting to work, but I think I solved this problem for now. I refered to [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/ptn4b7/comment/hdxov1t/).